# Summation of factorials is a perfect square number

Tags: summation, factorial, square-numbers

Find the values of n for which 1! + 2! + 3! +  ...  + n! is the square of a natural number.

My attempt : I tried to find the summation of factorials upto n terms.
Let the summation of first n factorials be $S_n$
$$S_1=1$$
$$S_2=3$$
$$S_3=9$$
$$S_4=33$$
I could not find any generic way to find $S_n$ from this data points. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider the last digit of $S_n$ for $n \geq 4$. What do you observe? Can the number ever be a perfect square?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I got the sense. So the answers are 1 and 3 only.