# Prove that $0!+1! + 2! + 3! + ..... + n!$ $\neq$ $p^\text{r}$, where $n \geqslant 3$ and $n$, $p$ and $r$ are three integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, factorial

> Let $n$, $p$ and  $r$ be three positive integers. Prove that for $n \geqslant 3, r>1$, $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k! \neq p^\text{r}$$

**SOURCE:** BANGLADESH MATH OLYMPIAD (Preaparatory Question)

I am not so familiar with such a this kind of problem. Seeing that problem, I became little bit curious about what the text states and what will be its conception?

I couldn't solve the problem. Moreover, I don't know about the formula of **$\sum k!$**. Is there any? And I couldn't realize the essence of **$p^\text{r}$** and what the reason is behind the fact the summation can't be equal to $p^r$ for some integer $p$.

Any kind of reference or conception will massively help me start with some approach to solve the above problem. Thanks for your support and effort in advance.

Comment: Three real? It is obvious but they are integers it is more interesting

Comment: @Ameryr I am very novice and little experienced at this case. You can suggest me a edit and I will be highly glad to approve it.

Comment: done! Edit the subject change it from real numbers into integers

Comment: Considering $n$ is one of the limits of $\sum$ here, that one at least must be an integer

Comment: Aren't there any other additional restrictions? Otherwise the result _is_ true for some choices of $p$ and $r$. Specifically, one could choose $r = 1$ and $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n k!$...

Comment: There must be more conditions here. Otherwise, set $r = 1$ and $p = \sum_k k!$.

Comment: @guy It says $n\geq 3$, $r>1$ in the question guys.

Comment: @Infiaria it didn't originally :P

Comment: @guy But I found no condition in there. Then is my text unclear or something context missing?

Comment: Well, here's a related question on the [formula for sums of factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this). $$\sum_{k=0}^n k! = \frac{1}{e}\left( \mathrm{Ei}(1) + i\pi + (-1)^{n+1}\Gamma(n+2)\Gamma(-n-1,-1) \right) $$ where $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ is the exponential integral and $\Gamma(x,a)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Remove 0! and you get another interesting problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question asks about the prime factorisation of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!$. The first thing to notice is that you have $0!=1!=1$ and all the other terms are divisible by 2, so the sum is divisible by 2. Thus if we are looking for a counterexample, we must have $p$ even, and so since $r>1$, $4$ divides the sum.

Now, the sum begins $0!+1!+2!+3!=10$, and then all terms after this are $k!$ for $k\ge4$. Thus, for $n\ge3$, $4$ does not divide the sum, a contradiction.

Comment: What is counterexample? I haven't read yet anything about it. Would you please clearify the point that for $n \geqslant 3$, 4 doesn't divide the sum? Besides, the power of 2 would have to be 2 or 1. Except this, the solution was very helpful.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy A counterexample is an instance of a claimed general rule failing, making it false. So if it's claimed $\sum_{k=0}^n n!$ is never a prime power, a counterexample would be a choice of $n$ for which it is. As Cambridge grad shows, such a counterexample would be a power of $2$. The point about divisibility by $4$ is that later factorials are divisible by $4!$ and hence $4$, and so later sums are, like $10$, $2$ more than a multiple of $4$.

Comment: I have made a quick edit, my proof was assuming $p$ prime, but it is easy to fix that.

Comment: My reference to prime powers was a mistake on my part too.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, I will solve the same problem but with $0!$ removed:

> Solve: 
>   $$1!+2!+\dots+n!=p^r$$
>   ...for $n,p,r\in N, r\ge2, n\ge3$

Denote the sum of the first $n$ factorials with $a_n$:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k!$$

It is obvious that for $n\ge3$:

$$3\mid a_n$$

Why is that so? 3 divides 1!+2! and 3 divides all factorials starting from 3! So the sum of factorials $a_n$ must be divisible by 3 for $n>3$. It means that the $p^r$ must be divisible by 3 which is possible only if:

$$3\mid p\iff p=3q$$

In other words:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k!=3^rq^r\tag{1}$$

Suppose that $r>=3$. It means that the right hand side is divisible by 27 and therefore it means that $a_n$ has to be divisible by 27 as well. Notice that 27 divides all factorials starting from $9!$. So if $a_8$ is divisible by 27, so it is $a_9, a_{10},\dots$.

You can check manually that $$a_8=1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!+7!+8!=46233$$

Therefore:

$$27\nmid a_8$$

Consequentially, for all $n\ge9$:

$$27\nmid a_n$$

So we have a contradiction for all big enough values of $n$. We just have to check a few starting values manually. Indeed, if you check all values from $a_1$ to $a_8$ you will see that only $a_7=5913$ is divisible by 27. But number $5913=3^4\times73$ is not of the form $p^r$.

So there is no solution for any $r\ge3$.

We have yet to consider a case for $r=2$:

$$a_n=p^2$$

It can be easily shown (see [proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864208/summation-of-factorials-is-a-perfect-square-number)) that:

$$1!+2!+3!=3^2$$

...is the only solution of the problem.

Comment: @Oldboy It's such an honor for me for your alternative effort. Outstanding for better learning process.

Comment: @AnirbanNiloy You are welcome. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @PeterTaylor Initially, I took $p$ to be a prime number but forgot to mention that. I have corrected my solution to allow for any possible value of $p$. This just made the problem more interesting, thanks for reporting the mistake.